# Shader program vs SpriteBatch

Tags: java, libgdx

I am trying to draw a Mesh with my own shaderProgram:

```
   private static String vertexShader = 
     "attribute vec4 a_position;    \n"
     + "attribute vec4 a_color;\n" 
     + "attribute vec2 a_texCoords;\n"
     + "uniform mat4 u_worldView;\n"
     + "varying vec4 v_color;"
     + "varying vec2 v_texCoords;"
     + "void main()                  \n"
     + "{                            \n"
     + "   v_color = a_color; \n"
     + "   v_texCoords = a_texCoords; \n"
     + "   gl_Position =  u_worldView * a_position; \n" +
     "}                            \n";
   private static String fragmentShader = 
     "#ifdef GL_ES                \n"
     + "precision mediump float;    \n"
     + "#endif                      \n"
     + "varying vec4 v_color;\n"
     + "void main()                 \n"
     + "{                           \n"
     + "  gl_FragColor = v_color;   \n"
     + "}";
```

in my `draw` method I use it for drawing some polygons:

```
public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {

  super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
  shader.begin();

  shader.setUniformMatrix("u_worldView", u_projTrans);
  mesh.render(shader, GL20.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
  Gdx.gl20.glLineWidth(15);

  shader.end();

}
```

I also add SelectBox to stage and after shaderProgram executes the first time, the SelectBox won't draw its selection list.

When I try to choose one from list - it would be chosen, but texture for list does not draw. I think the problem is in my shaderProgram, after using it the SpriteBatch can't re-draw texture for list of SelectBox.

```
public void render() {      
  Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.933333f, 0.933333f, 0.933333f, 1f);
  Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
  Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

  camera.update();

  batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
  batch.begin();
  stage.act();
  stage.draw();

  batch.end();
}
```

Why there is such a strange behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your `draw` method (the one that does the `shader.begin()` and `shader.end()`) is reached via the `stage.draw()` call?

If so, then your shader is active while the `Batch` instance expects to have total control over the OpenGL state in the GPU.  But when your `shader` runs, it will make changes to the OpenGL state that the `batch` does not expect.  The fix is to "end" the batch before enabling your shader.  Something like:

```
public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {

  super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
  batch.end(); // <---
  shader.begin();

  shader.setUniformMatrix("u_worldView", u_projTrans);
  mesh.render(shader, GL20.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
  Gdx.gl20.glLineWidth(15);

  shader.end();
  batch.begin(); // <--
}
```